# Generic Table Update by getting Substring in PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have a table **TABLE_5** with Second column COLUMN_2 having values as follows:

```
first_text_plan (1.1.1.1).txt
second_text_plan (1.1.1.2).txt
one_voice_data_plan (2.1.1.1).txt
one_3g_text_vo (3.1.1.1).txt

and so on.. (more than 500 records)
```

Now, i want to Update this column_2 for all the records so that, after Update COLUMN_2 should have following values:

```
first_text_plan
second_text_plan
one_voice_data_plan
one_3g_text_vo
```

How this can be done through PostgreSQL?

following query works for MySQL Databases:

```
UPDATE TABLE_5 SET COLUMN_2 = TRIM(SUBSTRING(COLUMN_2, 1, LOCATE('(',COLUMN_2)-1));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE table_5 SET column_2 = regexp_replace(column_2, '.\(.*$', '');
```